# Add multiple pictureboxes to form in C# from array

Tags: c#, arrays

I was trying to make a space invaders game using arrays to store the invaders, but each time I run the code it freezes and has the error about my array being the wrong size.

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Can anyone please help? Here is my code:

```
class invaders
    {
        ingame game = new ingame();
        PictureBox[] spaceinvaders = new PictureBox[100];
        public void spawn(int level)
        {
            PictureBox invader = new PictureBox();
            Bitmap img = (WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.SpaceInvader);
            for (int n = 1; n == 3 + level; n++)
            {
                for (int i = 12; i == 493; i = i + 37)
                {
                    invader = new PictureBox();
                    invader.Size = new Size(12, 12);
                    invader.Image = img;
                    spaceinvaders[i] = invader;

                    spaceinvaders[i].Location = new Point(i, n);
                }
            }
            game.Controls.AddRange(spaceinvaders);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please give us the exact error message

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: Note that neither of the `for` loops in your example can even be entered since the base condition is respectively `1 == 3 + x` and `12 == 943`. You need to use the `<` sign in this case.

Comment: I changed == to < and it is the same error. The error says it is on a line in the designer bit of the form "this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));" is the line it is on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition for your `for` loops are wrong. You need to use the `<` sign instead of `==`. The middle expression will be checked for each iteration and the loop execution will proceed only if the ouput of the check is `true`.

Since you ask the inner loop to go from `12` to `493`, it does that. Except that `493` is more than `100` and thus the array is accessed outside of its bounds so you should get an "array out of bounds" exception.

I could not reproduce your error. Please fix your code so it is reproducible.

Comment: How can I make it reproducible?

Comment: I have gotten the error to change to "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" saying that i need to make sure i don't have an infinite loop by changing all the "==" to "<="